# preg_match from preg_match using php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a problem in getting a match value.

I have this code

```
preg_match('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*)" \/><meta property=/s', $result, $lq);
$link = (string) urldecode($lq[1]);
echo $link;
preg_match('/url=(.*?)&_nc_hash/u', $link, $final);
print_r($final);
```

the problem is I cant get the value between the url= and &_nc

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, and thank you for commenting/reading my post
I have now the answer

I view sourced it and it was different from the output of the $link that it automatically convert by the browser.